# Possible to canonically digitize analog data to create public RNG?

Tags: information

Suppose you have a random data source, for which different observers will often, but not always, agree on a digitization. E.g. how many sun spots are visible from Earth right now, or what's the current pulse rate of a particular long-period pulsar relative to a millisecond pulsar. Each observer has his own camera or detector.

The goal is for each observer to independently produce the same canonicalized digitization. It's ok if some marginal/noisy data is excluded, but of course, all observers would have to make the same decision about what to exclude. It also doesn't matter what the particular data sources are (so long as all observers choose the same ones). And it's ok if the final bitrate is low, e.g. just a few hundred bits of entropy per day. The only requirements are that all observers must produce the same sequence of bits, without communicating among themselves while observing the data sources, and the data sources must be ones which nobody can influence or have prior knowledge of.

Is this possible?

Here's why I suspect it's impossible:
Observers won't see exactly the same signal. And their ADCs won't operate identically. Either one of those problems alone makes it possible that they'll get different raw bitstreams. And the original data sources obviously have no ECC. So, it seems not possible for the observers to agree on how to canonicalize the data.

Note, the situation is different if the data source was created according to some known digitization standard. E.g. two different floppy drives can read a floppy disk, and ensure they get the same canonicalized data, because the analog data source (magnetized disk surface) conforms to a standard for expected sampling rate and amplitude, which drastically reduces the risk of sampling a transition zone or an ambiguous level, and thus reduces the probability of the two observers (drives) producing different bitstreams, and even if they do produce different streams, the data source includes ECC data, which can be used to correct errors and produce canonical output. Neither of those things is the case for analog data from nature.

Comment: Yes, the trick is to find a source where the observer measure the same signal well enough to get a decent bandwidth. The faster the signal changes, then typically there is more noise and so observers will need to filter it down to a lower rate = less useful for sending data

Comment: I don't at all understand what you mean.

Comment: I think you're asking about a [book cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_cipher) (which you can make time-variable by using today's newspaper rather than a book), but you want a natural phenomenon rather than a man-made artifact. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Actually I just want to use the RNG, derived from natural events visible to all participants, as the starting signal for realtime computational proof-of-work races. By including the RNG's output in his computation for each race, each participant can prove that he didn't cheat by beginning the race early, but this requires all participants to agree on what the RNG output is. Hence my information theory question on physics.stackexchange instead of crypto.stackexchange.